# Writing unit tests for orchestration functions in Azure Durable Functions

Tags: moq, azure-durable-functions

I'm trying to learn how to write unit tests for durable function. Here is my code:

```
    [FunctionName("OrchestratorFunction")]
    public async Task RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
            var jobs = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<Job>>("JobsReaderFunction"), null);
            if (jobs != null && jobs .Count > 0)
            {
                var processingTasks = new List<Task>();
                foreach (var job in jobs)
                {                    
                    Task processTask = context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync("SubOrchestratorFunction"), job);
                    processingTasks.Add(processTask);
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);               
            }
    }

    [FunctionName("SubOrchestratorFunction")]
    public async Task RunSubOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)        
    {
            var job = context.GetInput<Job>();
            var group = await context.CallActivityAsync<Group>("GroupReaderFunction"), job);
            await context.CallActivityAsync("EmailSenderFunction", group);
            var canWriteToGroup = await context.CallActivityAsync<bool>("GroupVerifierFunction", job);            
            await context.CallActivityAsync("JobStatusUpdaterFunction", new JopStatusUpdaterRequest { CanWriteToGroup = canWriteToGroup, Job = job });
            await context.CallActivityAsync("TopicMessageSenderFunction", job);
    }
```

How do I write a test that covers Orchestrator, SubOrchestrator and Activity functions? Please let me know.

Here is my test so far:

```
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task VerifyOrchestrator()
        {            
            var jobs = <code to get jobs>
            var context = new Mock<IDurableOrchestrationContext>();           
            context.Setup(m => m.CallActivityAsync<List<Job>>("JobsReaderFunction", It.IsAny<object>())).ReturnsAsync(jobs);
            await _orchestratorFunction.RunOrchestrator(context.Object);
        }
```

UPDATE:

I updated the test method to:

```
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task VerifyJobs()
        {            
            var jobs = <code to get jobs>
            var context = new Mock<IDurableOrchestrationContext>();           
            context.Setup(x => x.CallSubOrchestratorAsync("SubOrchestratorFunction"), It.IsAny<object>())).Returns(() => _orchestratorFunction.RunSubOrchestrator(context.Object));            
            await _orchestratorFunction.RunOrchestrator(context.Object);
        }
```

which gives me an error:

[image]

```
context.Setup(x => x.CallSubOrchestratorAsync("SubOrchestratorFunction", It.IsAny<object>())).Returns(async () => await It.IsAny<Task>());
await _orchestratorFunction.RunOrchestrator(context.Object);
context.Verify(m => m.CallSubOrchestratorAsync("SubOrchestratorFunction", It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>()),Times.Once);
```

The above gives a null exception.

Answer (score 1):

The context is mocked acording to the line:

```
var context = new Mock<IDurableOrchestrationContext>();
```

This means that when you execute `Context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync("SubOrchestratorFunction")` moq search for setup for the method.
Because the method doesn't have any setup, it runs nothing and returns the default return value.

If you want to execute `RunSubOrchestrator`, you should setup it:

```
context.Setup(x => x.CallSubOrchestratorAsync("SubOrchestratorFunction", It.IsAny<object>())).Returns(() => _orchestratorFunction.RunSubOrchestrator(context.Object))
```

Comment: Thanks! When I add that line, it gives me error: no overload for method 'CallSubOrchestratorAsync' takes 1 argument. Could you please let me know why is that?

Comment: Fixed, the method signature wasn't clear from the question.

Comment: I get the above error after adding that line

Comment: I don't know your full implementation. But from your implementation, I understand that you want to run `RunSubOrchestrator`. So you need to run it as part of the setup.

Comment: Could you please let me know what code I should provide?

Comment: `context.Setup(x => x.CallSubOrchestratorAsync("SubOrchestratorFunction", It.IsAny<object>())).Returns(() => \* Execute RunSubOrchestrator *\)`